# `'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_score_'` - did I misunderstand the use of gridsearch?

Tags: scikit-learn, cross-validation, grid-search

I am attempting to accomplish a grid search in a linear regression model in sklearn. I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, star, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42)

alphas = np.array([100,10,1,0.1,0.01,0.001,0.0001,0])
Rmodel = Ridge()

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=Rmodel, param_grid=dict(alphas=alphas))

gridfit = Rmodel.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(grid.best_score_)
print(grid.best_estimator_.alpha)
```

**ERROR**

```
File "nlp2.py", line 77, in <module>
print(grid.best_score_)
AttributeError: 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_score_'
```

Did I overlook or miss any essential steps here? Thank you!!

Comment: You are using it wrong. Why not check the docs with a tons of examples? You created the ```grid``` object, but are fitting on the base-estimator ```Rmodel```. You have to fit on ```grid``` (the base-estimator object has no information of existence of the grid-object; it's different the other way around)! Also: ```fit``` does not return anything. Please check the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV).

Comment: Yes, indeed. I figured that out. Now it works. Thanks for your input.